# How to create repeating fields in REST with soapUI?

Tags: rest, soapui

I am trying to create a REST call in soapUI with a field that can be repeated.  Does anyone know how to make this work?  I can't seem to create a 2nd field with the same name and get an error when trying to add all the values in the single field.
ie, I am trying to send an email to multiple people

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find answer to same question I found this [link](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=6882) from soapUI support forum which gives the answer. 
There is property "Multi-value delimiter" in Request Properties in soapUI (bottom left corner). You need to specify this delimiter (for example "|") and then you can provide multiple values in soapUI using the delimiter which you specified (example: one|two|three, will send array of three elements: one, two, three).